# Search two values in a single cell and return the position of the first one found

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in Google Sheets where every cell in that column contains two words, i'm looking for some formula to extract only the first word, knowing that sometimes there is space between the two words and sometimes there is back to line instead of space.

I have tried this :
`=LEFT(C3180, FIND(" ", C3180)-1)`
And it worked in cells where there is a space between the two words.

I also tried this :
`=LEFT(C3180, FIND(CHAR(10), C3180)-1)`
And it worked in cells where there is back to line between the two words.

Finally i have tried this but it doesn't work :
`=LEFT(C3180, FIND(OR(" ",CHAR(10)), C3180)-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
=regexextract(A2,"(.*)(?: |\n)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try -in **each cell**- either of

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B31,"[a-zA-Z]+")
```

OR

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B31,"[[:alpha:]]+")
```

On the other hand, one can use a **single formula for a whole range**

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(
    REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B31,"[a-zA-Z]+")))
```

*(**Do** adjust each formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: Edit your second code and remove the last )) because it's not correct, and thank you for this formula it worked also.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Thank you. Still. My provided formula is more robust. Have [a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TSH2.png).

Comment: i actually use your formula with little modification, i found that the first one was not very perfect for my case but i don't blame "rockinfreakshow" because it's me who did not explain very well, his formula does not work in cells where there is more than two words, yours also did not work as i expected but as i said it's me who did not explain well, the words in the cell contains some numbers and (-) so i have modified your formula to "[a-zA-Z0-9-]+" and it worked exactly as i want, ..........

Comment: i tried to accept your both answers but i could not do that, i also tried to accept one and mark the other one as helpful but it gives me this : "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." sorry i'm new to this site so i don't know much about it,

Comment: anyway for future visit to this question, i consider both your answers are exactly true for the question i wrote, because i said the words are only two in a cell and between them there is either a space or a back to line that's it, but if there is numbers or special character in the first word, or there are more than two words, no one of them will work.

Comment: @TechREP *"...but if there is numbers..."* I see you worked out the numbers.  *"or special character in the first word"* works if NOT in the middle of a word, *"or there are more than two words, no one of them will work"*. [Not quite true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DBfp.png). That is what I meant by *"more robust"*.